# Using target_link_libraries on specific configurations (MinSizeRel, Release, etc.) instead of general ones (Optimized or debug)?

Tags: cmake

From what I see from the `target_link_libraries` documentation, you can set the keyword `debug`, `optimized` or `general` before a library to define for what configuration to link it to. The problem is that I would like to have even more control and be able to specify a different library for `Release`, `Debug`, `MinSizeRel` and `RelWithDebInfo`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `target_link_libraries` accepts [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), using which you may express almost any configuration-dependent logic.

Actually, specifying for `target_link_libraries`

```
debug libA
```

is effectively the **same** as using following generator expression:

```
$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:libA>
```

(More precise, it effectively the same with default setting of [DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_gbl/DEBUG_CONFIGURATIONS.html) variable.)

---

If you want to link different flavors of the same library dependent on configuration, then the better way is using an IMPORTED library target combined with [IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION_CONFIG.html) properties setting:

```
add_library(libA STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libA PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS "Debug;Release"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "/foo/bar/libA_debug.a"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "/foo/bar/libA_release.a"
    )
```

After that, plain

```
target_link_libraries(myExe PUBLIC libA)
```

will link with `/foo/bar/libA_debug.a` in 'Debug' configuration and with `/foo/bar/libA_release.a` in 'Release' configuration.