# How to determine current build type of visual studio in CMakeList.txt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

This is my build command in *CMD*:

```
cmake --build . --config Debug
```

This `Debug` can sometimes be `Release`, or sometimes it is the default. And I have a code in my `CMakeList.txt`:

```
if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE LLUd wstp64i4)
else()
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE LLU wstp64i4)
endif()
```

I think its grammar is fine. But it is a great pity that *Visual Studio*(multi-config generators) does not recognize the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable as [the document](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=cmake_build_type). How should I change it?

---

I have found a similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135272/how-to-determine-current-build-type-of-visual-studio-with-cmake), but it seem don't work for me.

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169148/using-target-link-libraries-on-specific-configurations-minsizerel-release-etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169148/using-target-link-libraries-on-specific-configurations-minsizerel-release-etc)

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks very much for your link. As that answer hints,  I found just fix my code into `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,LLUd,LLU> wstp64i4)` can solve my problem

Comment: "But it is a great pity" -- what's a pity is that the internet is littered with god-awful CMake tutorials that suggest it's okay to read the value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. It isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is all you should need:

```
find_package(LLU REQUIRED PATH_SUFFIXES LLU)

target_link_libraries(MyTarget PRIVATE LLU::LLU)
```

**If the above isn't working, you should ask about *that* error, not your attempted workaround.**

---

The code you show is broken on several levels. First, the value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` **should never be used** to check the active build type because it is not set when using a multi-config generator like Visual Studio. Every in-project use of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is a code smell. It is meant to be set by the person building your project (maybe you, maybe not) as a cache variable from the outside.

Second, what you are *actually* trying to do is to pick a different physical (i.e. on disk) library for `Debug` mode versus `Release` (and other `*Rel*`) mode(s). But this is handled by CMake already. You shouldn't have to do what you're attempting.

I'm assuming that `LLU` is the Wolfram LibraryLink Utilities. If so, you should [read the documentation](https://wolframresearch.github.io/LibraryLinkUtilities/basic/how_to_use.html) which shows very nearly the same code I gave above. Notice that `LLU::LLU` is an **imported target**. Unless Wolfram's LLU package is broken, this will handle per-config library selection automatically. If it is broken, you should complain to the developers, loudly.

The moral of the story is, as always, to **link to imported targets**. If what you're linking to doesn't have `::` in its name, you should be wary.

---

Here's a little background on why this is the case:

Imported targets that are generated by CMake's package export mechanism have the following properties set on them. These properties control CMake's view of which physical libraries should be used in which build types:

1. [`IMPORTED_LOCATION_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html#variable:CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_%3CCONFIG%3E) - This property names the path to the physical library that is to be used in the given configuration.
2. [`IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS.html) - This property contains a list of the configurations that have been imported for the given target.
3. [`MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_<CONFIG>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html#) - This is a per-config property that maps `<CONFIG>`, which should not be present in `IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS`, to a second config that *is* present in `IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS`. The physical library from the second configuration will be used.

Regarding point (3), some packages forget to map `MinSizeRel` and `RelWithDebInfo` to `Release`. If you are getting an error in these configs (but not in `Release`) you can add the following code to your project before importing any packages:

```
set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_RELWITHDEBINFO Release)
set(CMAKE_MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_MINSIZEREL Release)
```

This happens with LLVM's broken CMake packages. Most of the time, though, you don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: I've been using cmake for a few days and I've spent the whole day reading your answer. Thank you very much for your patience, I have learned a lot from it! As your hint, this is [my latest CMakeList.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/De2pC.png). It does simplify the content very much

Comment: @yode - that looks a lot better! Although... you should avoid hard-coding paths to your personal system. I'd recommend moving the `LLU_ROOT` variable to a [CMake preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html).

Comment: This is [original CMakeList.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytxrB.png), and this is [the CMakeList.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytxrB.png) after I dig your answer. Looks like I've got the problem solved.

Comment: It seems that I have solved the problem even better than expected. But I seem to have forgotten that key question (as the title) and it is not mentioned in your answer: **Can we check the active build type in CMakeList.txt (single-configuration generators and )?**. The *generator expressions*  in my above comment seem to be able to use in only a **few** functions. Is there a generic check method, and can you please add it to your answer?

Comment: @yode - I think you shared the same picture twice. To answer your follow-up question: **no, you cannot** determine the "active" build type in the CMakeLists.txt. It is simply ill-defined. Generator expressions are usable in **many** places and I have not yet encountered a situation where reading `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is necessary.

Comment: @yode - please ask a new SO Question